# Simultaneous Access Point and Wifi Client connection via bcm43430 chipset in systemd

Tags: systemd, wpa-supplicant, hostapd, broadcom

Since I have not been able to establish simultaneous Access Point(AP) and Wifi client(WCl) connection with bcm43430 chipset in systemd, I wanted to ask this question. If there is anyone who established simultaneous AP and WCL with bcm43430 in systemd,please your suggestion is really necessary for me.

Here is what I did: Firstly, in sysV based image, I created uapi0 virtual network interface over wlan0 network interface with iw dev .... Then, with hostapd, I could achieve to make access point with this uapi0. Parallelly, wpa_supplicant could connect to the wifi connection(in sysV).

However, when I started adjusting the system into systemd, the problems are occurring: I could establish separate connections. I mean, I created uapi0 virtual interface with iw, and wlan0.network, hostapd.network inside /etc/systemd/network. Then, after configuring wpa_supplicant.conf, I can connect to the wifi network. However, once I started hostapd after configuring hostapd.conf while wpa_supplicant is running, both connections (AP and WCl) are being lost. However, without prior wpa_supplicant connection, after starting hostapd, once I restart systemd-networkd, I can generate stable AP. These all provided by linux kernel 6.8 release and driver is brcmfmac. I have tried also to cross compile bcmdhd(AOSP), however after tackling strlcpy API issue(aborted from kernel 6.0 release), I have been facing cfg80211 incompatible issue.

If you have any suggestion on this issue, you are more than welcome. Thank you.

Comment: as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Please delete this.